# What can I use instead of soldering

Tags: soldering

Sorry for such a question.
I am not very dexterous and have no experience in soldering.

I have purchased some momentary buttons.

Some are already pre-soldered (both ends). The other others are just soldered to the button. The other end I need to solder onto some pins form my Raspberry Pi. Are there any 'adaptors/plugs' that  I can push the wire into and the other end plug over my pins.

This is what I purchased:

[image]

Total newbie so please forgive me.

Thanks

Comment: @jsotola Hi, thanks for commenting. I am sure I am doing some naming howlers here.  I pruchased this and these are what  I am trying to describe: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Momentary-Switch-PC-Power-45cm-Push-to-make-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-Flux-Workshop/113097321002?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649

Comment: @jsotola are you cyber-stalking me :)

Comment: @jsotola I was joking. I know I did not  look good with the previous question. An off day and was too brief with question. Will correct it though as people have voted for it and the answer did help me. Does the link help? Should I add it into my question?

Comment: if you add the picture to your post, then it will totally clarify your question

Comment: that connector shell has a small tab at each pin ... use a sewing needle to gently lift the tab and gently pull the wire at the same time ... the connector contact should slide out of the shell ... then you can put a piece of heatshink tubing over the end ... then you can push the wire onto a microcontroller board pin

Comment: @jsotola thanks i will do that

Comment: Others have a spring tab on the terminal that you push in rather than a plastic tab on the housing that you lift. Push in too hard though and it flattens and won't relock into another housing.

Comment: good video about heatshrink tubing ... https://hallroad.org/heat-shrink-tubing-and-sleeve-in-pakistan.html  .... all you need is a piece that is long enough to cover the sides of the metal contact plus 5 mm of the wire ... you can cover more of the wire of you like

Comment: I've used them without heatshrink but you don't want to plugging/unplugging live or poking at it as it is powered or else magic smoke.

Comment: @DKNguyen you can flatten the metal tab on the contact a bit and lift it again, but you can only repeat that a few times

Comment: @DKNguyen thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not solder those. You crimp them. They are not actually D-sub contacts but you can use a *open-barrel* D-sub crimper or something that looks similar for 0.100" female crimp terminals and housing. The official crimp tool for them is hundreds of dollars from the manufacturers that make the contacts so don't use them unless you need certification.

They go by many names from different manufacturers. Here is an example from Molex. If you are wondering what the difference is between the crimp terminals in the first two images, the difference is the first is high-force and the second one is normal force. Male crimp terminals also exist (and I think they use different crimp housings too).

[image]
[image]
[image]

Note crimping can take more finesse than it initially appears. Among other things, crimping the wrong depth into the terminal can bend the entire terminal (same way smashing the top center of a box pulls the sides and corners inwards) and make it not slide into the crimp housing. Also stripping enough so good contact is made with both conductive core and insulation for good grip. Crimping too hard with too small a die size means the force to pry the terminal out of the crimper ends up bending it. Particularly an issue when using crimpers not made specifically for your terminal (which cost hundreds of dollars).

Get more than you need and practice about five times so you can see what can go wrong.

[image]

From GreenLee

[image]

From Engineer

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111833/discussion-on-answer-by-dknguyen-what-can-i-use-instead-of-soldering).